# Error: OAUTH2 SERVER LIBRARY Unavailable

Tags: theming, authentication-authorization

I have a website in drupal version 8.3.3 and since I installed ***oauth2 server module***, I get the below error in *Admin -> Reports -> Status Report*

**The OAuth2 server library is required for the OAuth2 module to function. Download the library using composer, downoad it from GitHub or use composer manager.**

So I have added OAuth2 server library by running the below command

```
$ git clone --branch master https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php.git
```

This command executed successfully and also the files are created in libraries directory. But still I get the same error

**Note:** I followed the instruction from https://www.drupal.org/node/1938218

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, being new to Drupal 8 development, and this project currently lacking documentation for its use with Drupal 8, probably because it is currently only available through a "dev" edition.

The solution I used was to add the two oauth2-server-php Composer dependencies in the "composer.json" file at the root of the Drupal folder, which are currently:

```
"require": {
    "bshaffer/oauth2-server-php": "~1.7",
    "bshaffer/oauth2-server-httpfoundation-bridge": "~1.1"
}
```

Then install them with Composer by executing "composer install".

You can reach the project issue where I got help there: https://www.drupal.org/node/2897289#comment-12202222

Comment: unfortunately, I'm running into the same issue, but on a server where I'm not allowed to run composer. I only have file access (and db access). Thus, still I need to find out where to place the libraries to get Drupal 8 aware of them. This worked seemlessly in D7.

Comment: Hi @StephanRichter, have you found a solution since then? By default, Composer installs packages in a "vendor" directory. You could install them on a local computer, then upload all those files to your remote server, replicating what "composer install" would have done remotely directly.